# Python dictionary keys and values to Jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have python dictionary with components and links to that component, like

```py
result = {'component1': 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/component1/*view*/', 
'component2': 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/component2/*view*/', 
'component3': 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/component3/*view*/'}
```

And I need to split keys and values to Jinja template

```html
<div id="Backend">
  <h4>Backend:</h4>
     <ul>
       <li>Part1: {{Part1Status}} (component1, component2, component3)</li>
       <li>Part2: {{Part2Status}} (component3)</li>
       <li>Part3: {{Part3Status}} (component5, component6)</li>
     </ul> 
</div>
```

But! Components in html must be with links from the dictionary above.

```html
<a href="http://10.10.10.10:8080/component1/*view*/">component1</a>
<a href="http://10.10.10.10:8080/component2/*view*/">component2</a>
<a href="http://10.10.10.10:8080/component3/*view*/">component3</a>
```

Also do I need to use loops (for example) directly in html-template or in my python code?

UPD.

```py
x = list(result.keys())
y = list(result.values())

<div id="Backend">
 <h4>Backend:</h4>
  <ul>
   <li>Part1: {{Par1Status}} {% for key, value in result.items(): %}<a href={{value}}>{{key}}</a>{% endfor %}</li>  
     <li>Part2: {{Part2Status}}</li>
     <li>Part3: {{Part3Status}}</li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

I got close result as I expected, last thing it just split string with comma. Because now I have something like this:

```html
Part1: <Status> component1component2component2
```

but I want

```html
Part1: <Status> (component1, component2, component2)
```

Comment: So each part has a status and different number of components? Can you group the components by parts on the backend? E.g. `{'part1': {'status': 'p1 status', 'components': {'comp1': 'link1', 'comp2': 'link2'}}}`. If so, a general, loop-based solution can be created.

Comment: @Dauros I prefer to separate status because if I combine it together it will broke my logic from previous steps let's say

Comment: I just need to find a solution how to combine components and links in a list for html

Comment: So you have separate `result` variable for each part as well? Or how do you know which component belongs to which part?

Comment: @Dauros yes, I get the result for the dictionary from the files for each part (files contain components and links separately)

Comment: So every time a part changes you will go and edit this template file then restart the app? However if you are willing to group the data before passing it to the template I can provide a general loop based solution.